# ハンバーガーメニューの開閉が意図した通り動作しない

Tags: javascript

ハンバーガーメニューのリスト項目をクリックした後にメニューバーが閉じるように設定したいのですが、間違っている部分はわかりますか。

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav-wrapper');
    var hamburger = document.getElementById('js-hamburger');
    var blackBg = document.getElementById('js-black-bg');

    hamburger.addEventListener('click', function () {
        nav.classList.toggle('open');
    });
    blackBg.addEventListener('click', function () {
        nav.classList.remove('open');
    });
};

// メニュー項目をクリックしたときの処理
document.querySelectorAll('.sp-nav li a').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('.sp-nav').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<!-- ハンバーガーメニュー -->
<div id="nav-wrapper" class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="hamburger" id="js-hamburger">
        <span class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--1"></span>
        <span class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--2"></span>
        <span class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--3"></span>
    </div>
    <nav class="sp-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="header-nav__item header-nav__item--first"><a class="header-nav__link" href="#event">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="header-nav__item"><a class="header-nav__link" href="#about">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="header-nav__item"><a class="header-nav__link" href="#access">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="black-bg" id="js-black-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 情報不足です。何が合っていて何が間違っているというのでしょうか？ CSS フレームワークは何ですか？

Comment: 「スニペットを実行」をクリックするとスニペットの実行結果が表示されますが、そこにはエラーメッセージが含まれています。まずは、そこを足がかりにしてみては。